# To active update manager

Tags: update-manager

I dont have update manager in my netbook. My company seems like disabled it. I am still on ubuntu 10. many software never updated.can any one please help me out.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 10.04 or Ubuntu 10.10? This matters because 10.10 is not an LTS release, and is end-of-life (i.e., no longer supported), so you would have to change your configuration to update from old-releases software sources (and would be well advised to upgrade to 11.04 once you've done so).

Answer (score 0):

You should know 3 commands for your Terminal:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This should work ;)